# Can 4.0+ RTL library for WebView be packaged with apk for 2.2~2.3?

Tags: android, webview, arabic, right-to-left

We wanted to develop a web search app for Android 2.2+, and the language we're dealing with is Arabic script (RTL) based. We are using WebView as the rendering view.

So far only devices with Android 4.0+ (and some Sony phones whith 2.3) displayed the text correctly. But Android 2.x devices still consists a large part of our web users, we needed the same Arabic RTL support in Android 4.0 be availabe with our app.

To be clear, the mentioned Arabic support is not only the `direction:rtl` (which can be achieved with CSS), but more importantly a letter joining problem: most letters automatically change accroting to the previous and next letter when displayed.

On Windows, since 2000 version, there is a system shared library `USP10.dll` to handle the process. And applications have the file in their folder, would have the same support even on older Windows 98 systems.

Based on my research on the web, on android there are `libicuuc.so` and `framework.jar` to do the similar job.

**My question is**:

1. Since Android 4.0+ has the ability to hanlde the letter joining, is it possible to package the corresponding library with the apk to support Arabic in WebView?
2. If so, how (e.g where to put the file, and any code to add to activity)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add newer library for old sdk's. Old sdk's depend upon old java libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like we have to implement in our own library.